# Automatic link text for answer permalinks

Tags: feature-request, permalink, question-links

Referring to another answer on the site by a URL such as

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/difference-among-public-default-protected-and-private/33627846#33627846
```

gets nicely rendered as

> [In Java, difference between default, public, protected, and private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/difference-among-public-default-protected-and-private/33627846#33627846)

While this (which is the "share" / permalink version of the same answer):

```
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33627846/276052
```

is just rendered as is:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/33627846/276052

**Question 1:** Is there a reason for this? Personally I find the shorter permalinks a bit nicer, except for this drawback.

**Question 2:** Which URL should I use in my posts? The announcer, booster and publicist badges seem to encourage the use of the shorter form.

Comment: Concerning your "Question 2", for the sake of the badges it won't matter. From [the list of full badge descriptions:](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#188733) _"Only clicks from outside the Stack Exchange network count towards the badge"_

Comment: First link technically is a link to a question (with browser side navigation to answer), so it makes sense it is rendered with question's title. The second one clearly points to an answer which don't have any title.

Comment: @Alexei, I think the same applies to questions permalinks though.

Comment: @aioobe yes, permalink to question get rendered as nice text... so to me logic look reasonable: link to question - render with title, link to answer - render raw link.

Comment: Aha, ok, I didn't know that. I guess that explains the behaviour.

Comment: @Kendra What does that mean about Area 51 and SEDE? They have diverged from SE...

Comment: @Laurel I'm not sure about those two, actually. I would _assume_ clicks from those two don't count, but I could be wrong. I'm sure there's a question about it either here or on MSE.

Comment: Whoa! I did not know this feature existed! Sadly, it doesn't work in comments...

Answer (score 7):

The regex for links that automatically gets the title of the question is as follows:

```
/<a href="((\S+)\/q(?:uestions)?\/(\d+)(?:|\/\S*?))">\1<\/a>/g
```

<sub>This of course doesn’t apply to the Markdown but to the generated HTML.</sub>

We could change the share link to match this regex, for example by adding query string: `?hack=/q/123` (it doesn't break the link).

However, there's also another requirement. The first match, after having the `http://` part removed, can't contain any characters matched by this regex:

```
[^a-z0-9.]
```

that is, it can only contain lowercase letters, digits and dots. With the direct URL, the first match (after removing the `http://` part) is:

```
stackoverflow.com
```

so it passes the test. With the share link, the first match is:

```
stackoverflow.com/a/33627846/276052?hack=
```

so it obviously doesn't pass.

I don't know if there's any way to make it work, but if I were you, I would just use the following Markdown to make a link:

```
 [Difference among 'public', 'default', 'protected', and 'private'](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33627846/276052)
```

If you're curious about details of the process, [look at the source](https://gist.github.com/Gothdo/f57812049f836207af8bfcc15747273f) (I cut that fragment from http://dev.stackoverflow.com/content/js/wmd.js).

Your second question has already been answered in comments by @Kendra:

> Concerning your "Question 2", for the sake of the badges it won't matter. From [the list of full badge descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#188733): *"Only clicks from outside the Stack Exchange network count towards the badge"*

Comment: I mostly use the `[Title](permalink)` syntax that you suggest, but it's cumbersome to copy/paste the title, and should the question title be updated, my link text would be obsolete.

Comment: @aioobe But even if you use the normal link, the title is not updated automatically when the question's title changes, because it's set by the browser in the moment of posting.